# How does to form JSON for ES bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to inject 100 million logs in ES. I am trying ES bulk API for this. But I am unable to create JSON file formate which is required for bulk API.

Sample JSON data:

```
{"_index":"alias270_logs_auqaautoadsync3co-2019-07","_type":"elastica_logs","_id":"PT5PRwAqzaRpsQOz1lWHeT","_score":null,"_source":{"city":"Pune","Object_type":"Session","account_type":"Internal","severity":"informational","facility":"Box","country":"India","Resource_Id":"testuser1@securletbeatle.com","longitude":"73.8626","instance":"699178","host":"199.85.125.11","_latency":166,"Activity_type":"Login","location":"Pune (India)","__source":"API","created_timestamp":"2019-07-14T15:45:31","_domain":"securletbeatle.com","latitude":"18.5332","inserted_timestamp":"2019-07-14T15:45:31","user_name":"fiftythousand28455","message":"User logged in","user":"fiftythousand28455@elasticaqa.net","test_id":"NspjeLc8TQ8Q_deloitte"},"sort":[1562223465000]}
```

I tried in my way and got setup JSON file like this

```
{ "index":{ "_index": "alias270_logs_auqaautoadsync3co-2019-07", "_type": "elastica_logs"} }

{"_source":{"city":"Pune","Object_type":"Session","account_type":"Internal","severity":"informational","facility":"Box","country":"India","Resource_Id":"testuser1@securletbeatle.com","longitude":"73.8626","instance":"699178","host":"199.85.125.11","_latency":166,"Activity_type":"Login","location":"Pune (India)","__source":"API","created_timestamp":"2019-07-14T15:45:31","_domain":"securletbeatle.com","latitude":"18.5332","inserted_timestamp":"2019-07-14T15:45:31","user_name":"fiftythousand28455","message":"User logged in","user":"fiftythousand28455@elasticaqa.net","test_id":"NspjeLc8TQ8Q_deloitte"} }
```

Error Message on POSTMAN:

**"error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API endpoint is `/_bulk`, and it expects the following newline delimited **JSON (NDJSON)** structure:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

**NOTE:** The final line of data must end with a newline character `\n`. Each newline character may be preceded by a carriage return `\r`. When sending requests to this endpoint the `Content-Type` header should be set to `application/x-ndjson`.

On Kibana,

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

With CURL,

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_local/my_doc_type/_bulk --data-binary  @/home/data.json
```

where `/home/data.json` should be like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "47280", "Quantity": "206", "Id": "975463711"}
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "21505", "Quantity": "222", "Id": "975463943"}
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "772107", "Quantity": "735", "Id": "974920111"}
```